# Windows 10: 10+ Seconds to bring up a text file

Tags: windows-10, ssd, usb-flash-drive

During initial access to a memory device (such as the SSD or USB flash drive) it can take 10+ seconds to bring up a very small text file.  What tests \ simple diagnostics can be done to understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Steps for diagnosis (in order):

1) Disable all antivirus (include Windows Defender) and try again (maybe restart before this). Antivirus are often reasons for slowdown due to too intensive recursive scans.

2) Use Task Manager to see which application is consuming resources. If this doesn't display much, a service could be trying to use the resources.

3) Use Resource Monitor and continuously monitor the window while opening the file to see what is using I/O and CPU time.

4) Try using a clean usb drive and then open the file from it, to ensure the problem is not caused by a faulty filesystem.

5) Boot live from Linux and see how this works (for motherboard and usb related issues). If Linux works fine and nothing till this step tells you anything, then your Windows is screwed and you need to reset / reinstall it.

6) If loading is slow even in Linux, try testing your hardware (especially memtest)